# use regex or in cat

Tags: regex, linux, unix, cat

I have some log files that end in times

```
1200.gz
1215.gz
1230.gz
1245.gz
1300.gz
```

When I want to search through all the 12 o'clock files, I do `zcat 12**.gz | grep whatever` but it usually takes too long. Is there a way to use a regex "or" `zcat 12(00|15)`? [This tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lpic1-v3-103-7/) makes it seem like I can just use square braces, but I get a `command not found` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `zcat and grep`? You can directly use [**`zgrep command`**](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm) to search for a pattern in compressed files:

```
zgrep 'whatever' 12{00,15}.gz
```

Comment: Thanks! is zgrep faster or slower in the context `zcat file.txt | grep 'id=1' | grep 'fid="500'`?

Comment: Well it does merge 2 piped commands into one so it should be better.

Comment: how could I chain my two greps with zgrep? could I include it all in one to make the grep faster?

Comment: You can use `zgrep -e 'pattern1' -e 'pattern2' 12{00,15}.gz`

Comment: documentation looks like `-e` only takes a pattern; can I use it with my literal stings `fid=500` and `id=1`?

Comment: Yes sure literal string will work. If you want multiple needles you can also use it like `zgrep -e 'fid=500|id=1' 12{00,15}.gz`

Answer (score 3):

That's nothing to do with the (z)cat command, it's a shell issue.

It seems like [good old brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) should work for this case:

```
$ zcat 12{00,15}.gz | grep whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns)

```
shopt -s extglob
zcat 12@(00|15).gz | grep text
```

Why not use `zgrep` if available

```
zgrep text 12@(00|15).gz
```